# Calculating the weights in ABC SMC (2 parameters and more)

Tags: bayesian, importance-sampling, approximate-bayesian-computation, sequential-monte-carlo

Im trying to implement ABC SMC for ODE model which has 2 parameters to estimate. I stopped in the step when calculating the weights as it appear in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/328384). My question is should I calculate the weights for each parameter separately and then use this weights to resample ( each parameter will have its own weights vector) !! or should I calculate common weight for all the parameters?

Comment: What do you mean the weights for each parameter? Are you doing some form of Gibbs ABC?

Comment: No,I estimate both parameters (beta and delta), in the same time. I calculate the weights for each accepted parameter pair separately. Thus, I will have two different  vectors of weights, one for beta and one for delta. Then I use this weights (after normalising) in the kernel to re sample. Is that correct or I suppose have a common vector of weights for both parameter! I'm confused.

Comment: You are supposed to have a single vector of weights, ie prior /  importance density. I do not understand where the two vectors of weights come from.

Comment: so the calculation of the weight for two parameters will be: w=prior(beta)*prior(delta)/  sum( weights[t-1,]*dnorm(beta)*dnorm(delta)), where dorm is the kernel density for beta and delta,  and weights[t-1,] is the weights from pervious population?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the case. Note that we recently studied a [Gibbs version of ABC](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13599) where ABC can be run one parameter at a time, but it would seem delicate to combine it with SMC.

Comment: Thanks, this help a lot.